# Ionic SASS variables seem's like doesn't working

Tags: ionic-framework, sass, frontend

I want change the background color. Like this:

```
$red: red;

ion-router-outlet, ion-header ion-toolbar{
  --ion-background-color: $red;
  --background: $red;
}
```

But it's doesn't working.

```
ion-router-outlet, ion-header ion-toolbar{
  --ion-background-color: red;
  --background: red;
}
```

Is it working... what is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In variables.scss I wrote:

```
...
--background-white: #F6F6F6;
...
```

And in the app.scss:

```
ion-router-outlet, ion-header ion-toolbar{
  --ion-background-color: var(--background-white);
  --background: var(--background-white);
}
```